# how to open .jar files with other projects in java netbeans( open .jar with path location)?

Tags: java, netbeans

I got the assignment from the office to find this code because it was used to create core bank applications

I have tried importing it as a library, it was successful but was rejected by the office

Comment: So, do you want to do reverse engineering to find the source code of an jar? Can you be more explicit about your problem?

Comment: I tried running .jar in another java project

Comment: File >> Project Properties >> Libraries >> Compile-Time Libraries; or.
File >> Project Properties >> Libraries >> Run-Time Libraries; or.
Tools >> Libraries (Library Manager) >> Library Classpath; or.
Tools >> Java Platforms (Java Platform Manager). 
I want the .jar file to be accessible as above but accessed by coding